Is the matrix function $X\mapsto \operatorname{trace}^2(X A - X B X + C) $ coercive?
I am trying to proof that the matrix function
$$X\mapsto \operatorname{trace}^2(X A - X B X + C),$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\setminus \{0 \},X\succ 0$ and $ C,B\succeq 0$, is coercive in the sense that
$$\lim_{\Vert X\Vert_2 \to \infty} \operatorname{trace}^2(X A - X B X + C) = \infty.$$
Background:
I am minimizing this matrix function with gradient flow and want to guarantee that gradient flow is not diverging. I have run a few numeric simulations and it appears that the objective function is coercive for $X\succ 0$. The original problem is a little different, where I generate $X\succ 0$ with another $C^\omega$ map. My background is control engineering.
What I have tried:

Reformulation: I noted that if $\Vert X A - X B X + C \Vert_2 \to \infty$ as $\Vert X \Vert_2 \to\infty$, then $\operatorname{trace}^2(X A - X B X + C) \to \infty$ as $\Vert X \Vert_2 \to\infty$, provided the eigenvalues of $X A - X B X + C$ have the same sign.
Lower bound attempt:
I attempted to establish a lower bound on $\Vert X A - X B X + C \Vert_2$ using the reverse triangle inequality $\Vert A - B\Vert\geq \vert \Vert A \Vert - \Vert B \Vert \vert$. Specifically, I tried to show
$$\Vert AX-XBX+C\Vert_2 \geq \sigma_{\min}(B)\Vert X \Vert_2^2-\Vert A\Vert_2 \Vert X \Vert_2-\Vert C\Vert_2.$$
However, I could not prove this bound conclusively.

Question:

Is the function $X\mapsto \operatorname{trace}^2(X A - X B X + C)  $ coercive for $X\succ 0$?
If so, how can it be formally proven? Are there alternative approaches to finding a lower bound?

